# verifying the strict inclusions

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, summation

Let $\omega $ denotes the set of all sequences and $\omega $ is a linear space together with coordinatewise addition and scalar multiplication and let

$l^\infty:= \{(x_k) \in \omega: \sup_k\mid x_k \mid< \infty\}$,
$l^1:= \{(x_k) \in \omega: \sum_k\mid x_k \mid< \infty\}$, $cs:=\{(x_k) \in \omega: \left(\sum_{k=0}^n x_k\right)  \in c \}$, $c:= \{(x_k) \in \omega:  (x_k)\ converges \}$ $c_0:= \{(x_k) \in \omega:  \lim_k x_k=0 \}$.

Then verify the strict inclusions   $l^1 \subsetneq cs \subsetneq c_0 \subsetneq c \subsetneq l^\infty \subsetneq \omega$.

Comment: i have not got any idea about how can i begin to prove it

Comment: The first inclusion claims, that every absolutely converging series also converges. The second states, that if the partial sums of a sequence converge, then this sequence converges to 0. The third sais, that if a sequence converges to 0, then it converges (which is obviously trivial). The fourth states that every convergent sequence is bounded, and the last is obvious, too. Now, prove that, and try to find counterexamples for the  converse assertions.

Comment: still given answer is not clear for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) $l^1\subset cs$: Let $(x_k)\in l^1$, that is, $\sum_{k\geq0}|x_k|<\infty$. From the triangle inequality we have $|\sum_{k=0}^nx_k|\leq\sum_{k=0}^n|x_k|$, and since the right hand side remains finite as $n\to\infty$, so does the left hand side. Thus, $(x_k)\in cs$. 
The inclusion is strict, because for $x_k=\frac{(-1)^k}{k}$ the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ converges, but is not absolutely convergent (harmonic series). Hence $(x_k)\in cs$, but $(x_k)\notin l^1$.

2) $cs\subset c_0$: Let $(x_k)\in cs$, that is $\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=0}^nx_k=c$ for some real $c$. Since $x_n=\sum_{k=0}^nx_k-\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}$ we see that $(x_n)$ is the difference of two convergent sequences. Thus, $(x_n)$ converges to the difference of the limits which is $c-c=0$ which implies $(x_k)\in c_0$. 
The inclusion is not strict: Take $x_k=\frac{1}{k}$. Then $(x_k)\in c_0$, but $\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ diverges (harmonic series again), so $(x_k)\notin cs$.

I'm pretty sure you can do the rest on your own ;)